# Как в запросе обозначить количество результатов на все (*), а от >=2?

Tags: sql

Нужно определить 2-ух и более сотрудников с фамилией «Иванов», чье имя начинается на "И". Как в данном запросе обозначить именно от 2?

SELECT * FROM employees 
WHERE LastName LIKE "Ivanov" AND First Name LIKE "i%";

Comment: в зависимости от диалекта есть ключевые слова TOP, LIMIT, FIRST, ROWCOUNT (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891789/sql-select-first-10-rows-only) уточните СУБД

Comment: А если будет меньше двух, то какой должен быть результат?